# Is there a way to rig another character to have the same weight paint?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

As you can see, I have 2 near identical low poly characters which I want to reuse animations for. Is it possible to somehow copy the weight paint from one to another? Although in the screenshot it looks as if they already have similar weight paintings for them but they aren't exact. I've tried Transfer Mesh Data but with no luck (but I'm not sure if I was doing it wrong? I first selected my male mesh followed by ctrl clicking my female mesh and then selecting transfer mesh data and then select vertex groups but the weights looked different in the end) Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/3uot2q/copy_bone_weights_to_another_object/
That looks like your issue. I googled "copy weight paint blender" .
specifically
`Go to 'Weights'>'Transfer Weights' from the menu to the left of [Weight Paint]`